# TeXStudio macro not showing in auto-completion

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I have created two macros in TeXStudio to input `figure` and `subfigure` environments with the abbreviations/usertags `\myFigure` and `\Subfigure` respectively, as shown below.

[image]
[image]

The *Figure* macro works as intended, showing up in the auto-completion marked with '(Usertag)', and inserts the predefined `figure` environment:

[image]

But when I try to use the *Subfigure* macro without the `\my*` prefix, nothing shows up

[image]

I've tried another macro with the abbreviation `\abcd` and that worked, too, so I don't think the `\my*` prefix is required. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXstudio seems to ignore case for usertag completion and only accepts lowercase input, so you have to start typing `\subfigure` with a lowercase `s`:

[image]

That was actually also the case for your `\myFigure` if you continue typing:

[image]

---

In case you are using uppercase letters in the abbreviations to avoid clashes with other commands, you don't need to worry about that, since your TeXstudio macros are not LaTeX macros/commands, despite starting with `\` as well. They are treated completely separately and may be identical to existing commands, as they aren't inserted in the code as-is, hence they can never cause any *already defined* errors.